# How to read tables from multiple webpages, and combine them with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I tried to web crawling using common for ~ loop twice.

I wanted the results to come out as below..

```
    Company  Title  Salary  Location  Start_date  End_date
0      A1
1      A2
2      A3
3      A4
4      A5
5      A6
.      .
.      .
.      .
6000 A6001
```

But my results were as follows...

```
    Company  Title  Salary  Location  Start_date  End_date
0      A1
1      A2
.      .
.      .
19     A20
20     A1
21     A2
.      .
.      .
```

Instead of getting each page, my result is the last page, repeated (i.e. A1~A20 was repeated 30 times).

I'm not certain what I'm doing wrong.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
import datetime


df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ('Company', 'Title', 'Salary', 'Location', 'Start_date', 'End_date'))

for i in tqdm(range(30), mininterval = 1):
    df_list = list()
    for n in range(20):
        print("Now", i, n)
        page = i + 1
        URL ="http://www.sisuljob.com/employ/employ_01.htm?tb=1&sca=&stx1=&stx2=&stx3=&sfl1=&sfl2=&sfl3=&page=" + str(page)
        req = urlopen(URL)
        html = req.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    
        df.loc[n] = [
            soup.select('.pd10_text > a')[2*n].text,
            soup.select('.pd10_text > a')[(2*n)+1].text,
            soup.select('.text_02 > a')[4*n].text,
            soup.select('.text_02 > a')[(4*n)+1].text,
            soup.select('.text_02 > a')[(4*n)+2].text,
            soup.select('.text_02 > a')[(4*n)+3].text,
        ]
        df_list.append(df)
    
    print(df_list)
df_all = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index = True)


#To_excel with today string file name.
today_string = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y.%m.%d_%Hh%Mm%Ss')
df_all.to_excel('Sisuljob_Raw_Data_(' + today_string + ').xlsx')
```

Comment: I have added an update to my answer that explains the issue with the original code. So you understand, it's actually a fairly tricky issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Original Code

- The issue with the original code is that dataframe `df` is an object that was created outside of the loop
- Each time the loop iterates, a pointer to the dataframe object `df` is added to `df_list`
- With every loop, `df` changes, therefore all `df` in `df_list` are the same, and change with each loop.
- That issue can be resolved by changing `df_list.append(df)` to `df_list.append(df.copy())`.

### Use [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)

- Lucky for you that entire page of html is marked with `<table>`, which can easily be read with [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)

  - The method reads each table into a list of dataframes
  - For these pages, the table you want, is and index 14
- Each of the tables at index 14 will be added to a list and then all the dataframes will be combined with [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the pages; 1 - 29 and append the table at index 14 to df_list
df_list = [pd.read_html(f'http://www.sisuljob.com/employ/employ_01.htm?tb=1&sca=&stx1=&stx2=&stx3=&sfl1=&sfl2=&sfl3=&page={page}')[14] for page in range(1, 31)]

# concat the list of dataframes
df = pd.concat(df_list)

# dropna columns and rows
df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='all').dropna(axis=1, how='all').reset_index(drop=True)

# add a column header
df.columns = ['Company', 'Title', 'Salary', 'Location', 'Start_date', 'End_date']
```

### `df`

```py
print(df.info())
[out]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 580 entries, 0 to 579
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------      --------------  ----- 
 0   Company     580 non-null    object
 1   Title       580 non-null    object
 2   Salary      580 non-null    object
 3   Location    579 non-null    object
 4   Start_date  580 non-null    object
 5   End_date    580 non-null    object
dtypes: object(6)
memory usage: 27.3+ KB
```

#### `df.head(20)`

```
|    | Company                 | Title                                                            | Salary    | Location   | Start_date   | End_date   |
|---:|:------------------------|:-----------------------------------------------------------------|:----------|:-----------|:-------------|:-----------|
|  0 | 문정현대지식산업센터    | 시설기사                                                         | 2800~2900 | 서울       | 2020-09-11   | 채용시까지 |
|  1 | 인성에스비엠            | 시설(영선)기사 구인                                              | 2600~2700 | 서울       | 2020-09-11   | 채용시까지 |
|  2 | IBS인더스트리           | 판교 신세계조선호텔 전기/소방 주임                               | 2900~3000 | 경기       | 2020-09-11   | 2020-09-25 |
|  3 | (주)맥서브              | 연합뉴스 빌딩                                                    | 2500~2500 | 서울       | 2020-09-11   | 채용시까지 |
|  4 | 힐스테이트암사APT       | 기전주임(격일제)                                                 | 3300~3300 | 서울       | 2020-09-11   | 2020-09-20 |
|  5 | 양재하이브랜드          | 전기주임(무제한선임)-직영                                        | 3700~3900 | 서울       | 2020-09-11   | 채용시까지 |
|  6 | 삼구 아이엔씨           | 강남 (대치동,논현동) 글래드 호텔 일근 기사 구함2 개지점          | 2500~2700 | 서울       | 2020-09-11   | 채용시까지 |
|  7 | 스마일게이트 홀딩스     | [스마일게이트 SPMC] 시설지원팀 전기/소방 안전관리자 모집         | 3200~3700 | 경기       | 2020-09-11   | 채용시까지 |
|  8 | 분당트라팰리스          | 시설전기 격일제                                                  | 3200~3300 | 경기       | 2020-09-11   | 채용시까지 |
|  9 | 주식회사 케이에스메이트 | 호텔 기계 주임 주간                                              | 2800~2800 | 서울       | 2020-09-11   | 채용시까지 |
| 10 | (주)조은시스템          | 시설                                                             | 3300~3400 | 서울       | 2020-09-11   | 채용시까지 |
| 11 | (주)이노서브비엠        | 스카이파크 대전1호점 전기팀장,시설기사 구인                      | 2800~3200 | 서울       | 2020-09-11   | 채용시까지 |
| 12 | (주)한결티엠에스        | 경기도 광주 관리소장 모집                                        | 3400~3600 | 경기       | 2020-09-11   | 2020-09-30 |
| 13 | 스마일게이트 홀딩스     | [스마일게이트 SPMC] 시설지원팀 전기/소방 관리 담당 (주임~대리급) | 2700~3000 | 경기       | 2020-09-11   | 채용시까지 |
| 14 | 스마일게이트 홀딩스     | [스마일게이트 SPMC] 시설지원팀 기계/설비 관리 담당 (주임/대리급) | 2700~3000 | 경기       | 2020-09-11   | 채용시까지 |
| 15 | (주)호리마이어          | 기전기사                                                         | 2400~2400 | 서울       | 2020-09-11   | 채용시까지 |
| 16 | 미소들의료재단          | 병원내 직영 시설관리 4교대 가능자 모집                           | 2700~2900 | 서울       | 2020-09-11   | 채용시까지 |
| 17 | 백상기업(주)            | 연2640 여의도 KB통합사옥 시설기사(전기파트)                      | 2600~2700 | 서울       | 2020-09-11   | 2020-09-14 |
| 18 | 백상기업(주)            | 월220 여의도 KB국민은행신사옥 건축주임 주5                       | 2600~2700 | 서울       | 2020-09-11   | 2020-09-11 |
| 19 | 백상기업(주)            | [월250/식사제공] 인하대생활관 기전기사 모집(전기산업기사)        | 3000~3000 | 인천       | 2020-09-11   | 2020-09-14 |
```

#### `df.tail(20)`

```
|     | Company                   | Title                                                                           | Salary    | Location   | Start_date   | End_date   |
|----:|:--------------------------|:--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|:----------|:-----------|:-------------|:-----------|
| 560 | (주)에프엠텍              | 시설관리                                                                        | 3200~3300 | 서울       | 2020-08-13   | 2020-08-31 |
| 561 | 주식회사 폴에이산업       | 오피스 건물 시설 주임                                                           | 2500~2500 | 서울       | 2020-08-13   | 채용시까지 |
| 562 | 토탈S.E.M시스템           | 롯데마트 서초점 시설관리                                                        | 2500~2600 | 서울       | 2020-08-13   | 채용시까지 |
| 563 | 리마크빌 영등포           | 시설주임 보일러,가스 선임필수                                                   | 3300~3400 | 서울       | 2020-08-13   | 채용시까지 |
| 564 | 위례오벨리스크            | 기전주임                                                                        | 3300~3300 | 경기       | 2020-08-13   | 채용시까지 |
| 565 | (주)고암                  | 방재기사                                                                        | 2500~2700 | 서울       | 2020-08-13   | 2020-08-25 |
| 566 | 압구정빌딩                | 기계실기사                                                                      | 3100~3200 | 서울       | 2020-08-13   | 채용시까지 |
| 567 | 서울농수산시장관리(주)    | (단기기간제근로자:일용직/시급:10,523) 시설파트단순노무종사원, 청소, 취사보조 등 | 1400~3000 | 서울       | 2020-08-13   | 채용시까지 |
| 568 | (주)아이비에스 인더스트리 | 신라스테이 광화문 시설기사모집                                                  | 2500~2600 | 서울       | 2020-08-13   | 채용시까지 |
| 569 | 지에스아이주식회사        | 고압가스 기능사 / 시설관리                                                      | 3000~3400 | 서울       | 2020-08-13   | 채용시까지 |
| 570 | 선재에이치알              | 전기주임 모집/일근                                                              | 2900~3000 | 서울       | 2020-08-12   | 채용시까지 |
| 571 | 한국주택시설관리(주)      | 상가관리소장                                                                    | 4000~4500 | 서울       | 2020-08-12   | 2020-08-14 |
| 572 | (주)삼구아이앤씨          | [삼구아이앤씨] 가톨릭대학교 시설기사 모집                                       | 2700~2800 | 경기       | 2020-08-12   | 2020-08-31 |
| 573 | 주식회사 큐원             | 기계기사 모집                                                                   | 2700~2700 | 서울       | 2020-08-12   | 채용시까지 |
| 574 | 백상기업(주)              | 월220이상 여의도 KB국민은행 방송기사(주임-대리) 모집 주5                        | 2600~2800 | 서울       | 2020-08-12   | 채용시까지 |
| 575 | ksnc                      | 기계기사 모집                                                                   | 2800~2900 | 서울       | 2020-08-12   | 채용시까지 |
| 576 | 아이비에스인더스트리      | 방재주임                                                                        | 2800~2900 | 서울       | 2020-08-12   | 채용시까지 |
| 577 | 성민종합사회복지관        | 시설안전관리인                                                                  | 2800~3000 | 서울       | 2020-08-12   | 2020-08-18 |
| 578 | (주)케이엠산업            | 전기기사(선임) 구인                                                             | 3600~3600 | 강원       | 2020-08-12   | 채용시까지 |
| 579 | 코오롱LSI(주)             | 시설(전기,소방/4교대)기사 채용모집 - 서울(여의도) FKI타워                       | 2700~2900 | 서울       | 2020-08-12   | 채용마감   |
```